# why does this k6 HTTP post fails?

Tags: javascript, https, k6

I have a curl command that gets a valid response and a 200 code.

```
curl --location 'https://amazonURL/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic XXX' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=client_credentials'
```

I get a response that contains  an access_token

I have a k6 script that contains the following call that is supposed to be the equivalent of the curl command above.

```
import http from 'k6/http';
import { sleep, check } from 'k6';
import encoding from 'k6/encoding';

  const url_auth = 'https://amazonURL/oauth2/token';
  const auth_payload = JSON.stringify({'grant_type': 'client_credentials'});
  const auth_params = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic XXX'
      }
  };

  let auth_response = http.post(url_auth, auth_payload, auth_params);
```

I get a 405 http code.
Anyone see what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: does your service support content negotiation if if not maybe try aligning Accept header/Content-Type headers with what it actually expect  as request and returns.

Comment: not sure but the headers in the curl command and the K6 script are identical. Any reason why one would require that and not other?

Comment: They are not identical - you are sending urlecnoded body with curl and a json with k6.

Comment: it will also be good if you can show what the actual responsed returned on an error is

Comment: `--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' …` != `headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json', …`